# Django - fetch data from Elasticsearch as QuerySet.

Tags: python, django

I have an ordinary ViewSet that fetch data from PostgesDB, applies some BackEnd filters etc.

All of the processing works thanks to the fact that Notes.objects.all() returns a QuerySet.

How do I turn a free Elasticsearch query result to QuerySet?

Alternatively, How do I turn a Dict into QuerySet?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Refer https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Comment: How do I turn the Response object into QuerySet object?

Comment: I don't think it's possible

Answer (score 0):

For those coming from google, this is how I achieved it, using the django-elasticsearch-dsl package.

```
fields = ['title', 'description']
s = ItemDocument.search().query("multi_match", fields=fields, fuzziness='AUTO', query='sutures').exclude("match", is_latest=True).highlight('title')

s.to_queryset() # this will return a queryset
```

Comment: be aware that this costs a sql request to retrieve the model instances with the ids returned by the elastisearch query

Comment: This is a very expensive operation for a result set of 10K. Is there a more efficient way to do this conversion? It's taking approximately 6 seconds.